# TextFields align with labels

Tags: html, css

I want all textfields and correspondings label to be on the same line.

[image]

```
<style>
    input[type="text"] {
        display: inline;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }
    label {
        display: inline;
        text-align: right;
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="firstTF"/><label for="first">First</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="secondTF"/><label for="first">Second</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="thirdTF"/><label for="first">Third</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fourthTF"/><label for="first">Fourth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fifthTF"/><label for="first">Fifth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="sixthTF"/><label for="first">Sixth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="seventhTF"/><label for="first">Seventh</label>
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap them in `<p>` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp71sqqt/)?

Comment: Yeap, great idea Vucko. I am relatively new on this platform but I am going to try your solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float both elements left, set `display: inline-block;` and add `clear:left;` to the input.

```css
input[type="text"]{
display:inline;
margin-bottom:10px;
width: 50px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
  clear: left;
}

    label {
        display: inline-block;
      float: left;
        text-align: right;
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="firstTF"/><label for="first">First</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="secondTF"/><label for="first">Second</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="thirdTF"/><label for="first">Third</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fourthTF"/><label for="first">Fourth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="fifthTF"/><label for="first">Fifth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="sixthTF"/><label for="first">Sixth</label>
<input type="text" value="Loading..." id="seventhTF"/><label for="first">Seventh</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Emmanuel. It works prefectly.Whenever SOF allows me to accept your code, then I will mark it

Comment: How to add a single space between textfield and label?

Comment: You could use margin.